# Can log into MySQL server, but Loading Data No Longer Works

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I was able to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to add txt file to my mysql table before, but now it is no longer working. I log into my mysql serve like this:

`mysql --local-infile -u  st4rgut25 -p -h edutechfinal.cqk0lckbky4e.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

I confirmed that my database (hosted on AWS server) has `local infile` set to 1. When I try to `LOAD DATA INFILE`, however, I am now getting this message:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'st4rgut25'@'%' (using password: YES)`

I was not seeing this message before. Any clues as to what might be going on and how I should resolve? Should I reset the pw?

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way of solving this:

1) log into ec2 instance
2) from ec2 instance connect to mysql server
3) LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE works now.